# error middleware for azure mobile apps async operations

Tags: node.js, azure, asynchronous, azure-mobile-services

I have an express app running with azure mobile services
the error middleware

```
// production error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
  ptlogger.error(err.message);
});
```

the issue is this snippet doesn't get invoked when inside the callback of a query result e.g.

```
   router.get('/id/:subscriberid', (req, res, next) => {

    var mssqlObject = req.azureMobile.data;
    var query = { sql: strSql };
    mssqlObject.execute(query).then( (results) => {
         console.log(unDeclaredVariable); // should hit the error handler here
    });
});
```

it would have hit the middleware if it was outside the async mssqlObject async call

Note: I don't want to use the .catch block cause i have multiple other scenarios where i'd like to solve the issue once and for all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this mobile services or mobile apps?  Also, how are you determining that the middleware is not hit?  Finally, you will need a .catch() block to capture the error if you are going to diagnose this without a breakpoint / debugger.

Comment: 1) it's mobile apps .   2) console.log(undefinedvariable) will hit the error handler if it's written anywhere above the mssqlObject.excute(que.... line .  3) I was hoping to centralize error handling without the need to write the .catch callback for every sql query code or any other async operation.

Comment: Add .catch((error) => { console.log(error); throw error; });

Comment: this will work but i was trying to avoid the catch/error callback for the every query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really an Azure Mobile Apps issue - it's more of a Node.js issue.

Add the following to your code:

```
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
});
```

This way you can catch the error locally, but also at a global level.